# Changing pictures in a website gallery form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, image, button

I have tried for about a week now and cannot solve my problem.
What I want to do is have a web page that will basicaly scroll through 5 or 6 pictures by `clicking a next or prev asp:button`. Can someone help me from scratch how to achieve this.

I am using visual studio web developer and have a blank web site made with a master page. I want to add this gallary function to the auto generated `Default.apsx` file.

My picture name are `pic001.jpg; pic002.jpg; pic003.jpg` and so forth

all I want is a button on the left saying previous which will take you to the previous image, a button on the right that says next which will show you the next picture and in the middle is a picture (the one that changes)

Please help with this problem I have tried and failed rather horribly at it,
Many thanks to the one who can help

This is some code of my attempts:

### Default.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Title="Default" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default"  %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server" >
    <script src="myJava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server" >
<table>
    <tr><td> GALLARY </td></tr> <!--Header-->
    <tr>
        <td> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Prev" OnClientClick="getPrevImage()"/> </td>
        <td> <img ID="pic" alt="" src="" runat="server" width="400" height="400" /> </td>
        <td> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClientClick="getNextImage()"/> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

### Default.aspx.cs file

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string script = string.Empty;
            script += "<script language='javascript'>";

            script += "init()";
            script += "</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Error", script);
        }
    }
}
```

### myJava.js file

```
var imagePath = new Array();
var imageIndex = 0;

function init(){
     addPath("pic001.jpg");
     addPath("pic002.jpg");
     addPath("pic003.jpg");
     addPath("pic004.jpg");
     addPath("pic005.jpg");

     getImagePath(0);
}

function addPath(path){
     var index = imagePath.length;
     imagePath[index++] = path;  
}

function getImagePath(index){
     var length = imagePath.length;

     if(index <= length){
        if(index >= 0){
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").src = imagePath[index];
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").alt = imagePath[index];
            imageIndex = index;
        }
     } else {
        document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").src = "DOES NOT EXIST";
        document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").alt = "DOES NOT EXIST";
     }
}

function getNextImage(){
     var length = imagePath.length;
     var index = imageIndex;
     if(index++ < length--){
        if(imagePath[index] != null){
            imageIndex = index;
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").src = imagePath[index];
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").alt = imagePath[index];
        }                                    
     }
}

function getPrevImage(){
     var index = imageIndex;
     if(index-- >= 0){
        if(imagePath[index] != null){
            imageIndex = index;
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").src = imagePath[index];
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").alt = imagePath[index];
        }   
     }
}
```

Comment: add some thing that you tried

Comment: Show us something you have tried so far, maybe it is usable

Comment: Why do you need to use an `<asp:Button>`? This can easily be done with html + jQuery. What have you got so far?

Comment: What is the problem with the existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are an approaching using html and jquery that you can easy use in your app:

HTMl (feel free to replace `<a>` with any tag that you want):

```
<a href="" class="previous">Previous</a>

<img src="1.jpg" class="display"/>
<img src="2.jpg" class="hide"/>
<img src="3.jpg" class="hide"/>
<img src="4.jpg" class="hide"/>

<a href="" class="next">Next</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(.previous).click(function(){
        var current = $(.display);
        //hide current img
        current.attr("class", "hide");
        //get previous img
        var pre = current.pre();
        if(pre !== null)
        {
            //display previous img if available
            pre.atrr("class", "display");
        }
        else
        {
            //dipslay last img if previous not available
            current.parent().find("img:last").attr("class", "display");
        }
    });

    $(.next).click(function(){
        var current = $(.display);
        //hide current img
        current.attr("class", "hide");
        //get next img
        var next = current.next();
        if(next !== null)
        {
            //display next img if available
            next.atrr("class", "display");
        }
        else
        {
            //display first img if next not available
            current.parent().find("img:first").attr("class", "display");
        }
    })
});
```

CSS (you can change the `display: block` to `inline` or anything that suit your requirement):

```
img.display {
    display: block;
}

img.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm not a pro html, css, jquery so hope this somehow help you

Comment: In theory that looks like it should work but I know nothing about JQuery... I only have limited knowledge of JavaScript. is there a way to do that using javascript instead of JQuery? I don't even know what's the difference between JQuery and JavaScript either

Comment: You should learn a little bit of jquery, this will help your life easier.